# PixelSearch occasionally not finding colours found by PixelGetColor

Tags: search, colors, autohotkey

I was trying to create a script which would perform an action when a colour is detected but experienced issues with PixelSearch.

I am using PixelSearch rather than matching with PixelGetColor as the colour is transparent and therefore requires PixelSearch Variation feature.

After experiencing issues with not finding a colour which was definitely there I tried to create a script to find a colour with PixelGetColor then pass it to PixelSearch and search for it with 0 variation.

This ensures that the colour was actually there, the script worked most of the time but frequently responded with ErrorLevel 1 (Not found which should be impossible).

I worked both on inactive and active windows but occasionally failed on both.

The script is posted below can anyone explain why this issue may be occurring 
All test colours were static and not changing images with no transparency.

Why does this error occur and can it be fixed?

```
CoordMode, Pixel,Screen
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen

*$PGDN::
    MouseGetPos, PosX, PosY
    PixelGetColor, cRGB , %PosX%, %PosY%,RGB
    PixelGetColor, cBGR , %PosX%, %PosY%
    PixelSearch,Colour_SearchX,Colour_SearchY,PosX+10,PosY+10,PosX-10,PosY-10,cRGB,RGB Fast
    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Search_Result:= "Found"
    }
    Else
    {
        Search_Result:= "Not Found"
    }
    MsgBox,% PosX ", " PosY "`nRGB: (" cRGB " ) - BGR: (" cBGR ")"  "`n" Search_Result ":" cRGB " at: " Colour_SearchX "," Colour_SearchY
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works the changes I made include

```
PixelSearch,Colour_SearchX,Colour_SearchY,PosX-10,PosY-10,PosX+10,PosY+10,cRGB,RGB Fast
```

This is because the search area numbers are wrong (X1,Y1 values are larger than X2,Y2)

```
CoordMode,Pixel,Screen
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen

*$PGDN::
    MouseGetPos, PosX, PosY
    PixelGetColor, cRGB , %PosX%, %PosY%,RGB
    PixelGetColor, cBGR , %PosX%, %PosY%
    PixelSearch,Colour_SearchX,Colour_SearchY,PosX-1,PosY-1,PosX+1,PosY+1,cRGB,50,RGB Fast

    If ErrorLevel = 0
    {
        Search_Result:= "Found"
    }
    Else
    {
        Search_Result:= "Not Found"
    }
    MsgBox,% PosX ", " PosY "`nRGB: (" cRGB " ) - BGR: (" cBGR ")"  "`n" Search_Result ":" cRGB " at: " Colour_SearchX "," Colour_SearchY
Return
```